# Update Model (adding element to List<Model>)

Tags: .net, instance, edit

There is a model:

```
 namespace WebApi.Entities
    {
        public class Category
        {
            public Category()
            {
                CategoryId = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
            }
    
            [Key]
            public string CategoryId { get; set; }
            public string Title { get; set; }
            public List<Item> Items { get; set; }
        }
    }
```

In CategoryService there is a method: `AssignItem`

```
    public void AssignItem(string id, Item Item)
    {
        var Category = _context.Categories.Find(id);

        Category.Items.Add(Item);

        _context.Categories.Update(Category);
        _context.SaveChanges();
    }
```

The arguments in function is:

- **`id`** - used to search the record for a specific id.
- **`Item`** - correct Item model delivered from frontend

I getting the error:

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object

in this line: `Category.Items.Add(Exercise);`

How to fix it - for assign item to specific category?

Comment: Yes - exactly - this doesn't exist - so need to add in constructor - and List will create when instance of class emergence. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your constructor, add a line for

```
public Category()
{
    CategoryId = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();= 
    Items = new List<Item>();
}
```

Your Items list is currently null.

Comment: Great - it's works - at least - now a duplicate Primary key has to be resolved.

Comment: Glad I could help. Please consider accepting the answer using the check mark! Thanks!